# Refresh List using Provider

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

**INTRODUCTION**

I am using a Database and a ContentProvider to fill a ListFragment. The problem is that ListFragment is not getting refreshed after I delete an item, I have to close and reopen the app to show the added item in the list.

I got this working well before, but after a modification I did in the code, this has started to happen and I don't know how to solve.

**DESCRIPTION OF WHAT CAUSES THIS**

From my main Activity, I call ListFragment via intent. As a fragment can't be called directly via intent, I call a FragmentActivity which functionality is only to start the ListFragment.

```
[Main] >> [FragmentActivity] >> [ListFragment]
```

As I have to handle single or dual pane, I created a layout which contais the Fragment, this is called `list_layout`.

**FragmentActivity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);
    //...

    if (mDualPane){
        MyPlacesListFragment listFragment = new MyPlacesListFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.list_fragment, listFragment).commit();
    }
    else {
        MyPlacesListFragment listFragment = new MyPlacesListFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, listFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

**list_layout.xml:** (for the single pane view, for the dual pane will be similar but in horizontal orientation and adding a Framelayout container)

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment 
        class="com.final.reversegeocoding.MyPlacesListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

The ListFragment uses a ResourceCursorAdapter so I use newVew and bindView methods. I'll only put the code refering to how I inflate the class ass I have checked that other code functionality is well done. Have to say that I inflate `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` as this is the layout I need to fill the list.

**ListFragment:**

```
final class PlacesCursorAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public PlacesCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, 0);
        //...

    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, parent, false);
        //...
```

**CONCLUSION**

Before I did't set the `setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);` in the FragmentActivity and it did it right the refreshing when I deleted an item.

But due to I have to handle single or dual pane, I've been forced to do this and now, when I delete an item, the list refreshes, but because it is contained in the FragmentActivity's `list_layout` and this is not refreshed until I exit and enter again the activity, the list is not getting refreshed inside of it.

**So my question is:** *How do I modify this code to get the layout refreshing without having to exit the ListFragment?*

Comment: you posted lots of not relevant code but did not post whats important: ContentProvider and how you delete an item

Comment: @pskink as I said, contentProvider's code is OK. I've worked with it before and did it's function right. It has started to do it wrong since I've declared the `list_layout`, so is not a problem with the provider's methods, is a problem with the layout's refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

After modifying your data, call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(),it will refresh your data

Comment: I do that. Again, this is not a problem with the provider nor the adapter, is a problem with the layouts declarations. The `list_layout` setted on the FragmentActivity does not update until I exit and enter on it again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as said in the post I knew that it had something to be with the layouts. I just had to modify the `list_layout` and the way I call it on `FragmentActivity` and it has started to work well again.

**FragmentActivity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);

    MyPlacesListFragment listFragment = new MyPlacesListFragment();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.list_fragment, listFragment).commit();
}
```

**list_layout.xml:** (for the single pane view, for the dual pane will be similar but in horizontal orientation and adding a Framelayout container)

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Framelayout
        android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />  
</LinearLayout>
```